# Background of ImageButtons

Tags: java, android-studio

I have one `ImageButton` and when I click him I want to pass image of background to other `ImageButton`.

I have `View v` of first `ImageButton`, and `imgB6` is the next `ImageButton`. I tried this but it gives an error:

```
findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackgroundResource(v.getBackground());
```

The error is `v.getBackgound()`

`v` is not `null`, and the error is in getting the `Background` of `v` I just want the `Background` of `v` on `imgB6`, How do I do it?

Comment: try adding what have you done so far.

Comment: public void Clicked(final View v)
{
         findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackgroundResource(v.getBackground());
}

just want put background of View Associate imgB1 to background of imgB6

How can I put image background of ImageButton1 on ImgeButton6

Comment: do error on "v.getBackground()" what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you let us know the error you are seeing? Make sure the views are inflating or being created properly (i.e. are not null). If `v` is null, you cannot get a background from it.

Comment: `v` is not null, and the error is in getting the `Background` of `v`
I just want the `Background` of `v` on `imgB6`, How do I do it?